# Generalization of Hölder's inequality with negative exponent

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, holder-inequality

> How can I prove that $(\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c)(\sqrt a+\sqrt b+\sqrt c)^2\ge 3^3$ using Hölder's Inequality

This cannot be done with the usual Hölder inequality, there is a negative exponent and $2$ between $0$ and $1$. And I couldn't find any generalization with those exponents. (There's one formula which holds for a different case [here](http://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/26/17.pdf#page=3))

Comment: The inequality itself can be proved by AM-GM:$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\geq3(abc)^{1/3}$ and $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\geq3(abc)^{1/6}$.

Comment: @yumero thanks but I want to apply Holder

Comment: Yes I know, hence that was a comment only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hölder is the following.

(In the following form much easier to use Hölder!)

Let $a_i>0$, $b_i>0$, $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$. Hence, we have:

$$(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^{\alpha}(b_1+b_2+...+b_n)^{\beta}\geq$$
$$\geq\left(\left(a_1^{\alpha}b_1^{\beta}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta}}+\left(a_2^{\alpha}b_2^{\beta}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta}}+...+\left(a_n^{\alpha}b_n^{\beta}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta}}\right)^{\alpha+\beta}$$

For your inequality $n=3$, $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=2$ and it's just Hölder!